# I have an error when trying to get Email From AspNetUser by account has FK with AspNetUser identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGsni.png)

This is the error to know that he appeared again and did not appear in the past and was bringing Email

`//I'm trying to get Email like this 
adminAccount.AspNetUser.Email`

Answer (score 0):

By the error it appears that adminAccount.AspNetUser is null.

Comment: in DB not null, but when trying to get Email by object adminAccount return null

Comment: there can be multiple of errors why you are not getting the data in object.. Like for example DB mapping errors,... What i wrote in the answer is the only thing I can on the screenshot.